# Datacontract with same names

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have 2 data-contracts having same names. What can I do?

Error:

> Types 'abc.Fruit' and 'abc.Fruit2010' both use the XML type name,
>   'Fruit', from namespace 'https://fruityshootee.com/'. Use XML
>   attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

```
[DataContract]
public class Fruit
{
  [DataMember]
   public string AttributeA;
}

[DataContract(name="Fruit")]
public class Fruit2010
{
   [DataMember]
   public string AttributeA2010;
}
```

Contract Names can't be changed :/

Comment: What do you want this to do? You can't have two datacontracts with the same name in the same namespace, yet you do force them to have the same name. Don't do that.

Comment: Is there any alternative

Comment: Not having the same name twice. Explain why you think you need this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 data-contracts having same names. What can I do?

You need to change one. You cannot have the same name twice in the same namespace.